# uses-permission(android)

Tags: android, permissions

Начиная с android 5.0 необходимо давать доступ приложению "в ручную" через настройки.

Как это можно сделать программно? Чтобы не нагружать пользователя лишний раз(заставлять его заходить в настройки и ставить флажки для разрешения доступа)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Это нужно делать с 6 версии. Делать нужно по способам, описанным в сети по запросу `android runtime permissions`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Android runtime permissions работают только с 6 андроида, а не с 5. Для общего представления можно почитать [эту](https://habrahabr.ru/post/278945/) статью. А так, воспользуйтесь библиотекой [PermissionsDispatcher](https://github.com/hotchemi/PermissionsDispatcher). Очень удобная библиотека.